# Is there Linux software that can read out times?

Tags: linux, software-rec, time, text-to-speech

I have seen how Mac can tell (and say) time on hourly, half-an-hour, or quarterly basis. This is very convenient because you can hear the Mac telling you what time it is.
I am looking for something like this on Linux. Anything that I can install to attain this?
Example:
At 10:15am, the computer will automatically says (as in speak):
"It's ten fifteen a.m."

Comment: Which [Linux distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) are you using? (e.g. Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, Gentoo...)

Comment: I am using Debian.

Answer (score 3):

The [Festival](http://packages.debian.org/en/squeeze/festival) text to speech application comes with an example script that says the current time.

All you would need is a cron job set to run at the times you wanted, running the script:

```
0 * * * * festival /path/to/saytime
```

This would have festival say the time at 00 of each hour.